# Error in make file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using the make utility in windows. Below is the output I get when I run `make -v`:

---

> GNU Make version 3.79.1, by Richard Stallman and Roland McGrath.
>   Built for Windows32 + cygwin sh.exe by mginzton@vmware.com
>   Copyright (C) 1988, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 2000
>           Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
>   There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> Report bugs to `<bug-make@gnu.org>`.

---

For some reason the make is not proceeding as expected and so I am trying to debug the same. But wherever I am trying to print  some statement like below I am getting an error message for that line:

```
 -- Makefile:17: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I am new to make files. Can someone let me know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: For your information, I am adding the following in the line 17

Comment: It would help if you showed us the whole makefile-- it's very short, isn't it? Is that statement in a rule? And does it begin with a TAB?

Comment: actually the whole make file is huge and I have added echo in the first line. Hers the snippet below                                                 echo "we are here"                                                        ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
SRCROOT := $(subst \,/,$(shell cmd /c cd))
else
SRCROOT := $(shell pwd)
endif
VALIDARCHS := x86 x64
DEFAULT_ARCH := x86

Comment: so my first echo line is causing the problem.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to add new information.  Comments cannot be formatted properly for showing examples and are very difficult to read.

Comment: One issue may be the age of your _make_ command. 3.79.1 is really very old. Are you sure your Makefile has no constructs that require _make_ 3.80, 3.81, 3.82, or (the current cygwin release) 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're a beginner in Make, you can't add something to a huge preexisting makefile and expect it to work. You have to learn the basics first.
2. An `echo` statement is valid in most shells, not in Make. Try `$(info we are here)`
3. The conditional in your "snippet" combines half a dozen difficult acts and contains at least two errors. You must learn these tricks one at a time. **Start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, and never add to code that doesn't work.**